Extract value from a function used in child component
Here is my parent
export async function SearchPage() {
  const [specializations, locations] = await Promise.all([getSpecializations(), getLocations()]);
  let specializaton: string = '';
  let location: string = '';

  const setSpecialization: (paramentr?: string) => Promise<string> = async (parameter) => {
    "use server";
    specializaton = parameter;
    return parameter;
  }
  const setlocation: (paramentr: string) => Promise<string> = async (parameter) => {
    "use server";
    return parameter;
  }

  return <div><MyCombobox mapOptions={specializations} onSelect={setSpecialization} />          <Link href={specializaton}>abc</Link>
</div>
}

I set in MyCombobox props.onSelect(selected.idSpecialization ?? selected.idLocation);
And get an error
enter image description here
How extract value from paramentr from function setSpecializaton to use later in link component
